# Getting NoSuchElementException using Scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer, nosuchelementexception

I am getting the infamous NoSuchElementException when reading from a "|" delimited text file using the scanner class. I am taking the values of each token and assigning them to values within a separate class using setter methods. I can't seem to pinpoint the error.

Here is my code:

```
void readFromFile(String fileName)
{
    operas.clear();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        Opera opera = new Opera();

        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");

        while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            opera.setTitle(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            opera.setComposer(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            opera.setYear(Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken()));
            opera.setCity(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            opera.setSynopsis(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            opera.setLink(stringTokenizer.nextToken());

        }
        operas.add(opera);
    }

    input.close();
}
```

And the text file is written as such (sorry it's so lengthy):

```
Giulio Cesare|George Frideric Handel|1724|London|Tells the story loosely based on the events of the Roman Civil War (48-47 B.C.) in which Julius Caesar has defeated Pompey and gone to Alexandria in search of him. The kingdom, ruled by Cleopatra and younger brother Ptolemy, is met by Pompey pleading for refuge from his conqueror.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1UmvCaobDg
Carmen|Georges Bizet|1875|Paris|Set in Seville around the year 1830, the opera deals with the love and jealousy of Don José, who is lured away from his duty as a soldier and his beloved Micaëla by the gypsy factory-girl Carmen, whom he allows to escape from custody.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTDMvyj4TFg
Die ZauberFlote|Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart|1791|Vienna|The Queen of the Night persuades Prince Tamino to rescue her daughter Pamina from captivity under the high priest Sarastro; instead, he learns the high ideals of Sarastro's community and seeks to join it. Separately, then together, Tamino and Pamina undergo severe trials of initiation, which end in triumph, with the Queen and her cohorts vanquished. The earthy Papageno, who accompanies Tamino on his quest, fails the trials completely but is rewarded anyway with the hand of his ideal female companion Papagena.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fm-4LdLFr_E
Il Barbiere di Siviglia|Gioachino Rossini|1816|Rome|Count Almaviva comes in disguise to the house of Doctor Bartolo and serenades Rosina, whom Bartolo keeps confined to the house. Figaro the barber, who knows all the town's secrets and scandals, explains to Almaviva that Rosina is Bartolo's ward, not his daughter, and that the doctor intends to marry her.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p97ym1HeCNI
Tosca|Giacomo Puccini|1900|Rome|Tosca is tale of romance over politics; featuring a heroic painter, a despicable ruler and an opera superstar, Tosca herself!|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGDhQwsgMBQ
Salome|Richard Strauss|1905|Dresden|Under the bright moonlight, guard captain, Narraboth, intensely watches Princess Salome, with whom he is madly in love, from a terrace above the banquet hall as she dines with her stepfather and his court.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kInyoCPyFb0
War and Peace|Sergei Prokofiev|1944|Moscow|Based on Tolstoy's literature of War and Peace, the world-weary Prince Andrei Bolkonsky encounters the youthful Natasha Rostova, first in the country, then at a ball in St Petersburg. Enchanted, he asks for her hand in marriage. Unfortunately Natasha has also aroused the curiosity of the dissolute Anatol Kuragin.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nhOeGhWWkU
Dido and Aeneas|Henry Purcell|1689|London|Tells the tale of the legendary Queen of Carthage, Dido, and the Trojan refugee prince, Aeneas. When Aeneas and his crew become shipwrecked in Carthage, he and the Queen fall in love. In the meantime, witches plot Dido's destruction.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3Vs3YXQp5U
Norma|Vincenzo Bellini|1831|Milan|Gaul has been conquered by the Romans. Oroveso, the Arch-Druid longs to lead a Gallic rebellion against the colonial forces. He and all the others wait for the signal to be given by his daughter, the Druid High Priestess Norma. But Norma has fallen in love with the Roman Proconsul, Pollione, and given birth to two children. They have been brought up in secrecy by her confidante Clotilde. Norma still loves Pollione but he has fallen in love with a novice priestess, Adalgisa.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GN75XDDm_DI
Rigoletto|Giuseppe Verdi|1851|Venice|Its tragic story revolves around the licentious Duke of Mantua, his hunch-backed court jester Rigoletto, and Rigoletto's beautiful daughter Gilda. A curse is placed on both the Duke and Rigoletto by a courtier whose daughter the Duke has seduced with Rigoletto's encouragement. The curse comes to fruition when Gilda falls in love with the Duke and sacrifices her life to save him from assassins hired by her father.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlr9jygEgwM
```

And the error I'm recieving:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at Operas.OperasGUI.readFromFile(OperasGUI.java:118)
    at Operas.OperasGUI.<init>(OperasGUI.java:45)
    at Operas.OperasGUI.main(OperasGUI.java:607)
```

Another note is that the error at line 118 is the line where I'm setting the year, the only line I'm parsing a primitive value. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Any suggestions? If any more code or info is needed, I'd be happy to provide it.

Thank you.

EDIT:
Here is my complete Operas class:

```
package Operas;

public class Opera {

    private String title;
    private String composer;
    private int year;
    private String city;
    private String synopsis;
    private String link;

    public Opera(){
        title = "";
        composer = "";
        year = 0;
        city = "";
        synopsis = "";
        link = "";
    }

    public Opera(String title, String composer, int year, String city,
            String synopsis, String link)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.composer = composer;
        this.year = year;
        this.city = city;
        this.synopsis = synopsis;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Opera(Opera anotherOpera)
    {
        title = anotherOpera.title;
        composer = anotherOpera.composer;
        year = anotherOpera.year;
        city = anotherOpera.city;
        synopsis = anotherOpera.synopsis;
        link = anotherOpera.link;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getComposer() {
        return composer;
    }

    public void setComposer(String composer) {
        this.composer = composer;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getSynopsis() {
        return synopsis;
    }

    public void setSynopsis(String synopsis) {
        this.synopsis = synopsis;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Opera{Title = " + title + ", Composer = " + composer + ", Year = " + year + 
                ", City = " + city + ", Synopsis = " + synopsis + ", Link = " + link + '}';
    }

    public boolean equals(Opera opera)
    {
        return this.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(opera.getTitle()) &&
                this.getComposer().equalsIgnoreCase(opera.getComposer());
    }
}
```

Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Use debug message , i want say use syst&#232;me.out.print for show all value of op&#233;ra (title , year,...) Juste After you set they :) . Whit that i know you can see the probleme

Comment: Why are you using a while loop to get tokens? 1) it looks like you already know how many tokens to expect, and 2) if you were going to use a while, you'd check before getting each token. Myself I wouldn't even use a StringTokenizer, a class that is almost deprecated, and instead would use `String#split(...)` to split the String into a String array.

Comment: Just remember that `split` is using regex where `|` is special character (representing OR operator) so you need to escape it like `String[] tokens = line.split("\\|");`.

Comment: I tried to debug the file, and I got to the third line of the text file when reading it, in which it got to the    SetYear and then it just stopped, and I could no longer step into it anymore, without providing an error. This is how our prof showed us to do it, and I want to be able to add as well as edit or delete more operas if I wish.

Comment: I think we need an MCVE.  I was unable to duplicate the error.

Comment: I notice that you got the error in the third line, and I notice that the *second* line contains some characters like "é".  Is it possible that your character encoding has gone wonky somehow?  If you get rid of the non-standard characters, does THAT get rid of the error?

Comment: Not really related but you didn't override `equals(Object)` method but you overloaded (created additional one) `equals(Opera opera)`. Always add `@Override` annotation to methods when you are attempting to override.

Comment: D M - I actually was thinking about this, as I'd copied and pasted the Synopsis for each Opera, and it actually worked! I need to go through and retype them, but my GUI is showing up now! Thank you so much, I should've caught that. Really dumb mistake to make, and a rather weird explanation to the errors provided, but as of right now things are looking up. I will keep updated with progress and other questions if I find anything else messed up.

Comment: Since that's the problem, it would be interesting to know what your IDE is, and how your character encoding is set (if you know.)

Comment: Here is what you can do: catch the exception, then wrap it in your own exception (use the original as cause). The message of the new exception should contain the line where the error ocurred and the toString of the Opera object that was being read (make sure toString works when not all fields are set). That should give you enough information to pinpoint the problem. You can also use the debugger to extract the same data

Comment: I use NetBeans (per request by my professors), which after investigation does not actually handle UTF-8 text files, although I'm not sure what the default is upon standard installation.

Comment: But I'm using NetBeans too, and it worked for me even with the special characters.

Comment: Oh, that is weird. I found a YouTube video posted last year describing the necessary steps to implement it, and they'd mentioned that as NetBeans comes by default, it was not supported. For some reason when I changed the special e character you mentioned, the GUI loaded onto the screen unlike before, but there was a special a character as well that I hadn't changed that just showed up as a box (unsupported character), which is why I was so confused how that actually solved the error.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what you are doing wrong here, the code I have which I believe mimicks your code is:

**MAIN:**

```
    package helpMe;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;

    import javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthSeparatorUI;

    public class getIt {

        static ArrayList readFromFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
        {

            ArrayList<Opera> a = new ArrayList<Opera>();

            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

            while(input.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                Opera opera = new Opera();

                StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");

                while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    opera.setTitle(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                    opera.setComposer(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                    opera.setYear(Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken()));
                    opera.setCity(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                    opera.setSynopsis(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                    opera.setLink(stringTokenizer.nextToken());

                }
                a.add(opera);
            }

            input.close();
            return a;
        }

        public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            ArrayList<Opera> a = new ArrayList<Opera>();
            a = readFromFile("thisIsAFile");
            for(int i = 0; i< a.size(); i++) {
                Opera o = a.get(i);
                System.out.println(o.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**OPERA CLASS:**

```
    package helpMe;

public class Opera {

    private String Title;
    private String City;
    private int Year;
    private String Composer;
    private String Synopsis;
    private String Link;

    public Opera(String t, String c, int y, String co, String s, String l) {
        Title = t;
        City = c;
        Year = y;
        Composer = co;
        Synopsis = s;
        Link = l;
    }

    public Opera() {
        Title = "";
        City = "";
        Year = 0;
        Composer = "";
        Synopsis = "";
        Link = "";
    }

    public String setTitle(String t) {
        return Title = t;
    }

    public String setCity(String c) {
        return City = c;
    }

    public int setYear(int y) {
        return Year = y;
    }

    public String setComposer(String co) {
        return Composer = co;
    }

    public String setSynopsis(String s) {
        return Synopsis = s;
    }

    public String setLink(String l) {
        return Link = l;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String s = Title + City + Composer;
        return s;
    }
}
```

**TEXT FILE**:

```
    Giulio Cesare|George Frideric Handel|1724|London|Tells the story loosely based on the events of the Roman Civil War (48-47 B.C.) in which Julius Caesar has defeated Pompey and gone to Alexandria in search of him. The kingdom, ruled by Cleopatra and younger brother Ptolemy, is met by Pompey pleading for refuge from his conqueror.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1UmvCaobDg
Carmen|Georges Bizet|1875|Paris|Set in Seville around the year 1830, the opera deals with the love and jealousy of Don José, who is lured away from his duty as a soldier and his beloved Micaëla by the gypsy factory-girl Carmen, whom he allows to escape from custody.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTDMvyj4TFg
Die ZauberFlote|Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart|1791|Vienna|The Queen of the Night persuades Prince Tamino to rescue her daughter Pamina from captivity under the high priest Sarastro; instead, he learns the high ideals of Sarastro's community and seeks to join it. Separately, then together, Tamino and Pamina undergo severe trials of initiation, which end in triumph, with the Queen and her cohorts vanquished. The earthy Papageno, who accompanies Tamino on his quest, fails the trials completely but is rewarded anyway with the hand of his ideal female companion Papagena.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fm-4LdLFr_E
Il Barbiere di Siviglia|Gioachino Rossini|1816|Rome|Count Almaviva comes in disguise to the house of Doctor Bartolo and serenades Rosina, whom Bartolo keeps confined to the house. Figaro the barber, who knows all the town's secrets and scandals, explains to Almaviva that Rosina is Bartolo's ward, not his daughter, and that the doctor intends to marry her.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p97ym1HeCNI
Tosca|Giacomo Puccini|1900|Rome|Tosca is tale of romance over politics; featuring a heroic painter, a despicable ruler and an opera superstar, Tosca herself!|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGDhQwsgMBQ
Salome|Richard Strauss|1905|Dresden|Under the bright moonlight, guard captain, Narraboth, intensely watches Princess Salome, with whom he is madly in love, from a terrace above the banquet hall as she dines with her stepfather and his court.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kInyoCPyFb0
War and Peace|Sergei Prokofiev|1944|Moscow|Based on Tolstoy's literature of War and Peace, the world-weary Prince Andrei Bolkonsky encounters the youthful Natasha Rostova, first in the country, then at a ball in St Petersburg. Enchanted, he asks for her hand in marriage. Unfortunately Natasha has also aroused the curiosity of the dissolute Anatol Kuragin.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nhOeGhWWkU
Dido and Aeneas|Henry Purcell|1689|London|Tells the tale of the legendary Queen of Carthage, Dido, and the Trojan refugee prince, Aeneas. When Aeneas and his crew become shipwrecked in Carthage, he and the Queen fall in love. In the meantime, witches plot Dido's destruction.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3Vs3YXQp5U
Norma|Vincenzo Bellini|1831|Milan|Gaul has been conquered by the Romans. Oroveso, the Arch-Druid longs to lead a Gallic rebellion against the colonial forces. He and all the others wait for the signal to be given by his daughter, the Druid High Priestess Norma. But Norma has fallen in love with the Roman Proconsul, Pollione, and given birth to two children. They have been brought up in secrecy by her confidante Clotilde. Norma still loves Pollione but he has fallen in love with a novice priestess, Adalgisa.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GN75XDDm_DI
Rigoletto|Giuseppe Verdi|1851|Venice|Its tragic story revolves around the licentious Duke of Mantua, his hunch-backed court jester Rigoletto, and Rigoletto's beautiful daughter Gilda. A curse is placed on both the Duke and Rigoletto by a courtier whose daughter the Duke has seduced with Rigoletto's encouragement. The curse comes to fruition when Gilda falls in love with the Duke and sacrifices her life to save him from assassins hired by her father.|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlr9jygEgwM
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    Giulio CesareLondonGeorge Frideric Handel
CarmenParisGeorges Bizet
Die ZauberFloteViennaWolfgang Amadeus Mozart
Il Barbiere di SivigliaRomeGioachino Rossini
ToscaRomeGiacomo Puccini
SalomeDresdenRichard Strauss
War and PeaceMoscowSergei Prokofiev
Dido and AeneasLondonHenry Purcell
NormaMilanVincenzo Bellini
RigolettoVeniceGiuseppe Verdi
```

Not sure if that helps but it seems to work just fine and I run into no problems reading from the text file at all.

Comment: "your code works" is not an appropriate answer. We need to either wait for more code to see exactly what the problem is, or close the question as unanswerable.

Comment: More info: [Are “works for me” answers valid?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118992), [Are “Your code works fine for me” answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277923)

Comment: Would it be better to say, the way I implemented your code as shown here works? Obviously I assumed his class structure for Opera and used an ArrayList to hold them all in but using this method I do not receive an error when reading from the file like he does, which is what he is trying to fix.